# BMW 2007 530xi starts and dies after a few seconds

Tags: starting, coolant, bmw

A few days ago I replaced my upper coolant hose due to a leak. After replacing the hose, I decided to pour distilled water in the coolant reservoir ( so that I don't just waste any coolant ) just to see if there are any more leaks. I attempted to start the car, but now after it starts, it stays on for a few seconds then it sounds like it's struggling to stay on, it revs itself for another second or two then dies. Could it be that it is struggling to stay on solely because of the distilled water?

I have ISTA+ it if it helps, I'm just not too familiar with it on how to use it to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is, no the water has no effect on the starting. My first step would be to check all connector under the hood. You may have bumped one or forgot to hook one back up after your repairs. Then if that's good check for trouble codes. Then check fuel supply. You may have a bad fuel pump and\or filter.

Comment: Agree that the water would have no effect. First thing I'd do is put a code reader on it and check things. I had a no start once after replacing the clutch in a Ford Escape. Checked the codes and it told me the Crank Position Sensor wasn't receiving a signal. Easy fix and started right up. The OP's problem sounds like it could be a cam position sensor, but who knows for sure.